# Некорректно отображается сайт на Iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема со стилями. На всех устройствах сайт отображается нормально, а вот на айфоне только пол шапки, не могу понять в чем причина.

http://musicteacher.website/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложи скрин, при эмуляции все нормально

Comment: Добавила скрин в вопрос, грузится только пол шапки на всех браузерах в iphone. В андроид все ок, планшеты, ноуты, компы тоже.

Comment: @AndreyFreiz какая эмуляция? Хромовская? Она не работает, если что

Comment: добавьте минимально необходимый код. ваш вопрос и ответы на него должны быть потенциально полезны для сообщества, в данный момент это не так.